# Laravel Eloquent - method to obtain 'grandchildren' where grandparent_id matches

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have the following relationship:

```
Tool:
-----
id
name
description


Competency:
-----------
id
name
description
tool_id


Indicator:
----------
id
name
description
competency_id
```

I'm trying to obtain all the indicators (*i.e. grandchildren*) which fall directly under a specified tool. The relationships are that tools has many competencies, and competencies has many indicators.

My (*pseudo*) code so far is:

```
hasManyThrough('Indicator', 'Competency', 'tool_id', 'competency_id')->where('tool_id', '=', 1)->get();
```

I think I'm going down the right lines, but having trouble getting the code right.

Comment: I think you want tell "*tools has many competencies, and competencies has many **indicators** (not tools)*" no?

Comment: yes, my error. I'll update this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get indicators for the indicated competency.**

```
$indicatorsOfCompetency = Indicator::where("competendy_id", $yourCompetencyID)->get();
```

or, depends of your *laravel relationships names*:

```
$competency = Competency::find($yourCompetencyID);

$indicatorsOfCompetency = $competency->indicators()->select(["id","field1","field2"]);
```

**Get indicators when his competency it's related to the indicated tool.**

```
// Note: Depending of your Laravel version, could be "lists" or "pluck" function.
$competencyIDS = Competency::where("tool_id", $yourToolID)->lists("id");

$indicators = Indicator::whereIn("competency_id", $competencyIDS);
```

or more *eloquent*, using `whereHas()`:

```
$indicators = Indicator::whereHas("competency", function($qCompetency) use ($yourToolID){
    $qCompetency->whereHas("tools", function($qTool) use($yourToolID){
        $qTool->where("id", $yourToolID);
    });
});
```

Comment: We're trying to pass in the tool_id and filter for only indicators which fall directly underneath, disregarding the competencies. How does the above allow us to do this, since we're not referencing any competency_id?